# Como hacer un require de un archivo en otro subdominio de forma segura con PHP

Tags: php

Quiero hacer un `require de PHP` desde un archivo alojado un un sobdominio (*ej1.dominio.com*) a otro, en otro sudominio (*ej2.dominio.com*).

Lo que quiero saber es **si es seguro** y **la mejor forma de hacerlo** porque he llegado a ver en algunos sitios que puede ser "peligroso" si no sabes qué estás haciendo.

Comment: Tratándose de subdominios no hay problemas de seguridad en sí, es como requerir un archivo en una carpeta cualquiera siempre dentro del entorno del dominio principal. Un subdominio no es más que una subcarpeta dentro del dominio principal. Tu estructura es algo así, supongo: `dominio->public_html` y dentro dos sub-carpetas: `ej1` y `ej2`. Puedes usar sin problema archivos de `ej1` en `ej2`y vicev. Otra cosa sería que `ej1` o `ej2` no esté protegida adecuadamente, de ser así, sería todo el entorno el que correría peligro, independiente de un `require` o de un `include`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la biblioteca [cURL](http://php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php), o la función [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php). Te recomiendo que uses certificados SSL para evitar un ataque Man in the middle.

También puedes usar una firma para asegurarte de que no fue modificado el archivo.